# How to get a TableViewCell like Phone.app-"Recents tab" or Mail.app-"mail list"

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I need a List like this:

---

"my-Title" . . . . . . . . . . . "10:20AM"
"Created-by: meadlai"
"TitleString" . . . . . . . . . . . "09:33AM"
"Created-by: meadlai"
"TextLabel" . . . . . . . . . . . "11:59AM"
"detailTextLabel"

---

There are three fields: title,creator,time.
It almost like the **Phone.app** "Recents-Calls" style.
or the **Mail.app**'s mailList. I don't think it needs a custom-UITableViewCell.
May I create a list like it with the System-UITableViewCell?
any clue or code? appreciate you very much.

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = @"Victoria";cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"created-by:mead";  how to add the time on the right side?

Comment: Finally, I make it out......,using accessoryView<br>    cell.textLabel.text = @"Victoria";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"created-by:mead";
            UILabel* time = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,80,20)];
            time.text = @"05:59 PM";
            cell.accessoryView = time;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe change the `accessoryView` of the cell, as there is no 'style' like the the one you want. Still, a custom cell class might make things easier.

An enumeration for the various styles of cells.

```
typedef enum {
   UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
   UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
} UITableViewCellStyle;
```

The type of standard accessory control used by a cell.

```
typedef enum {
   UITableViewCellAccessoryNone,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
} UITableViewCellAccessoryType;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Some Name";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Some text underneath";

    return cell;
}
```

Specifically this line of code let's you have a TableViewCell like phone.app

```
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

   UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer [UITableView](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-add-uiimage-and-uilabel-in-the-uitableview/)

Hope this will help you solve all your issues....

Answer (score 1):

```
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Victoria";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"created-by:mead";
        UILabel* time = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,80,20)];
        time.text = @"05:59 PM";
        cell.accessoryView = time;
```

Done.

Comment: I have made it out...haha  Thanks for all replies.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the cell can't have a DetailDisclosureButton, which is something the Phone.app still has.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a quick solution that still allows the use of a `DetailDisclosureButton`, you could use a library like [TDBadgedCell](https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell), which allows you to place a badge on the left hand side of a cell. If you don't want the badge to be highlighted, just set `badgeTextColor` and `badgeColor` accordingly.